# Wordpress Site Health Cannot read property 'applyFilters' of undefined

Tags: wordpress, health-check

wordpress version 5.6, PHP 7.4.10 64bit. Launching the Site Health page from the admin console I get this js error, visible through the chrome console:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'applyFilters' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (site-health.min.js?ver=5.6:2)
    at c (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.6:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.6:2)
    at l (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.6:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[chunk_0]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.6:2)
```

The Site Health page remains continuously "Loading results ..."

If it helps, I extracted the facility information from the Site Health tab = debug.
Does anyone already know the problem and know how I can fix it?

Thanks a lot to everyone

Comment: Forgive me, I only realized now that this is the worst place to ask this question. Excuse me

Answer (score 0):

WordPress 5.6 [updates jQuery in the admin to the latest version](https://make.wordpress.org/support/2020/12/handling-potential-jquery-issues-in-wordpress-5-6/). This may stop some old plugins from working, and this is likely affecting your Site Health function. One of your plugins most likely needs updating.

- Disable all plugins, see if issue remains.
- Enable plugins one by one until the issue returns.
- Ask the plugin author to update the plugin or switch to another.
- Install the [jQuery Migrate Helper plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate-helper/)

Some of the features no longer working will just stop working behind the scenes without any apparent problem.

The jQuery Migrate Helper plugin will let you downgrade to a previous version of jQuery.